# Combine multiple time-series rows into one row with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using a recurrent neural network to consume time-series events (click stream). My data needs to be formatted such that a each row contains all the events for an id. My data is one-hot encoded, and I have already grouped it by the id. Also I limit the total number of events per id (ex. 2), so final width will always be known (#one-hot cols x #events). I need to maintain the order of the events, because they are ordered by time.

Current data state:

```
     id   page.A   page.B   page.C      
0   001        0        1        0
1   001        1        0        0
2   002        0        0        1
3   002        1        0        0
```

Required data state:

```
     id   page.A1   page.B1   page.C1   page.A2   page.B2   page.C2      
0   001        0         1         0         1         0         0
1   002        0         0         1         1         0         1
```

This looks like a `pivot` problem to me, but my resulting dataframes are not in the format I need. Any suggestions on how I should approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea here is to `reset_index` within each group of `'id'` to get a count which row of that particular `'id'` we are at.  Then follow that up with `unstack` and `sort_index` to get columns where they are supposed to be.

Finally, flatten the multiindex.

```
df1 = df.set_index('id').groupby(level=0) \
    .apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)) \
    .unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)  # Thx @jezrael for sort reminder

df1.columns = ['{}{}'.format(x[0], int(x[1]) + 1) for x in df1.columns]

df1
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can first create new column with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new column name, then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html). Then you need sort columns in level `1` by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), remove `MultiIndex` from columns by `list comprehension` and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df['g'] = (df.groupby('id').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)

df1 = df.set_index(['id','g']).unstack()
df1.sort_index(axis=1,level=1, inplace=True)
df1.columns = [''.join(col) for col in df1.columns]
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
print (df1)
   id  page.A1  page.B1  page.C1  page.A2  page.B2  page.C2
0   1        0        1        0        1        0        0
1   2        0        0        1        1        0        0
```